# How to handle concurrent file write access with a filestream/streamwriter?

Tags: .net

Getting this error :-

> ERROR--->PerformanceAnalysis.Page_Load--->5/4/2023 12:44:36 PMThe
> process cannot access the file
> 'L:\path\path1\BatchLog\BatchLog04May23.txt' because it is being used
> by another process.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
> String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
> FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
> FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
> SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy,
> Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)    at
> System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
> access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
> msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

My code is writing the file and load is occuring at the same time. What should i do to resolve this.
any other way to write this because in this function it is not able write error or batch logs at the same time from multiple user.

public static void WriteToLog(string pstrDescription, Exception pobjException)
{

```
        StreamWriter swErrorLog;
        if (pobjException == null)
        {
            swErrorLog = File.AppendText(strBatchLogPath);
        }
        else
        {
            swErrorLog = File.AppendText(strErrorLogPath);
        }
        try
        {
            if (pobjException == null)
            {
                swErrorLog.Write(pstrDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                swErrorLog.Write(pstrDescription);
                swErrorLog.Write(pobjException.Message);
                swErrorLog.Write(pobjException.StackTrace);
            }
            swErrorLog.WriteLine();
            swErrorLog.WriteLine();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            swErrorLog.AutoFlush = true;
            swErrorLog.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.